# wordpress.org disallowing my plugin becuase of loading core files in cron cpanel file

Tags: php, wp-config, cron, include, wordpress.org

I made a plugin and trying to install on wordpress.org but Wordpress is giving me error message that ## Calling core loading files directly is incorrect.

I am using a cron file in my plugin.This cron can be set via CPanel also. That's why I have to include **'wp-config.php'** and I am including this as

```
include '../../../wp-config.php';
```

My cron file path is something like this

```
https://www.abc.com/wp-content/plugins/klicktip/cron_execute.php?redirect=1
```

Please help me how to include wp-config file so wordpress.org allow my plugin to install on wordpress.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to install the plugin via cron?

Comment: @WisdmLabs no I am not installing plugin via cron.I am using cron to make some queries.This cron can be set in Cpanel for particular time in a day.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the wrong way. What you might consider to to is to create an `wp_schedule_event` and then run `http://www.abc.de/wp-cron.php` per cPanel-Cron, that should work and will be a better way in the "idea" of WordPress.

**-Edit-**

Create an `cron.php` (or whatever you would like to call that file) in you plugin. Than from the main php file include that cron.php file.

```
if (wp_next_scheduled('myActionRunCron') === FALSE) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'myActionRunCron');
}
```

And then register an Action-Handler to that Action `myActionRunCron`

```
add_action(
    'myActionRunCron',
    'myCronAction'
);
```

And in the `cron.php`-File, place an function named myCronAction. Thats it.

```
function myCronAction() {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Than this Action will be run through WP each Hour. You can modify that by modify the `wp_schedule_event`-Call.

How to configure the Cronjob in cPanel could be found here [on Hostgator](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job)

Comment: can you please give an example how to do this.I mean a file which will run with wp_schedule_event and cpanel cron.Also I am already setting wp_schedule_event and in this function I have given the path of same file

Comment: I will edit my upper answer

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta now I updated my answer, that should give you many ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you should never try to include `wp-config.php` or any other of the loaders files from the plugin
2. your plugin should never be accessed by a direct url bypassing the WP initialization process.

The way you need to write your plugin is to check if there is a specific parameter to the URL, and only if it exists your code will do its thing.

Now you can setup your cron to `wget` the the specially crafted URL and you are done.